# Why is the topology on $\mathbb R$ always defined to be the set of "open" sets?

Tags: general-topology, definition, real-numbers

The "standard topology" on $\mathbb R$ contains all the "open sets" on it. By open sets I don't mean "the sets that are in the topology", which would make the statement a tautology, but I mean the open intervals $(a,b)$, (which we can talk about prior to defining a topology).

**My question is, why don't we define the "standard topology" as the topology generated by all the "closed intervals"? Why do we single out the open intervals only?**

Comment: This is really just a mathematical convention. A collection of open sets is the bare minimum one needs to discuss continuity, connectedness, compactness, convergence, etc. Of course by specifying open sets you have also specified closed sets, continuous maps from the space to itself and convergent sequences. So in a way, a topology really contains a lot more information than just open sets but as I said, the open sets are the bare minimum and all the other pertinent topics follow from them.

Comment: In cases like this it is of utmost importance that everyone knows **what is meant** by "standard topology". How it is defined does not matter. If someone knows what it is, then he can make his own definition. For me "standard topology" on $\mathbb R$ is the order topology. It is the smallest topology that contains the rays $(-\infty,a)$ and $(a,\infty)$ for every $a\in\mathbb R$. So we can even do it with less.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to other answers let me write about a motivation behind the concept of topology.

Originally people were working with metric spaces $(X,d)$. But they quickly realized that there are properties sort of independent on $d$. For example for any $r\in\mathbb{R}$, $r>0$ consider

$$d_r:X\times X\to\mathbb{R}$$
$$d_r(x,y)=\min(d(x,y),r)$$

it can be easily seen that each $d_r$ is a metric and there are at least infinitely many different $d_r$ in the sense that there is an infinite subset $D\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ such that if $r,s\in D$, $r\neq s$ then $d_r(x,y)\neq d_s(x,y)$ for some $x,y\in X$.

But the following holds:

> **Lemma.** Let $Y$ be a metric space and $f:X\to Y$ a function. Then $f$ is continuous in $d$ if and only if $f$ is continuous in $d_r$.

So even though these are different metrics they imply the same concept of continuity. That's because what really decides about continuity is those smaller and smaller values of $d$, not those "big" values of $d$. This idea led people to create the concept of topology. By isolating these properties of $d$ that decide about continuity.

And once it was created it was clear how to define a topology from a metric:

> **Definition.** Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Call a subset $U\subseteq X$ "metric-open" if and only if for any $x\in U$ there is $r\in\mathbb{R}$ such that the open ball $B(x,r)=\{y\in X\ |\ d(x,y)<r\}$ is fully contained in $U$.

It can be shown that the set of all "metric-open" subsets of $X$ forms a topology on $X$. And this topology plays well with the metric:

> **Lemma.** Let $X,Y$ be two metric spaces and $f:X\to Y$ a function. Then $f$ is coninuous in the metric sense if and only if $f$ is continuous in the topologies generated as defined above.

Note that it is essential to define the topology via **open** balls (corresponding to open intervals in $\mathbb{R}$). Otherwise (for example if you define via closed balls) the lemma is not true. Generally there's only one topology generated from closed balls (note that singletons are closed balls): the discrete topology, i.e. everything is open and everything is continuous. Boring.

Also note that topologies determine continuity uniquely in the following sense:

> **Lemma.** Let $X$ be a set with two topologies $\tau_1, \tau_2$. The following are equivalent:
>   
>     1. $\tau_1=\tau_2$
>   
>     2. For any topological space $Y$ and any function $f:X\to Y$ we have that $f$ is continuous in $\tau_1$ if and only if $f$ is continuous in $\tau_2$.

So the concept of topology is the one that describes continuity uniquely. Unlike the concept of metric. I'm not saying that metrics are useless or worse. They are very important and have their applications elsewhere. But in this particular context topology is better.

With that in mind the definition of the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$ comes from the standard metric on $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. the Euclidean one $d(x,y)=|x-y|$. Note that the definition you gave and the one I give are equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

Closed intervals can be singletons, so the topology generated by the closed intervals is the discrete topology. Not very interesting, not very useful.

Open intervals are the de facto standard of how we think about open sets. Every point lies "inside the set", and in $[0,1]$, neither $0$ nor $1$ lie inside the set from a topological perspective. They lie on the boundary of the set.

Finally, you can also argue that the topology is an order topology, and thus generated by open intervals by definition; or the metric-induced topology, which is generated by open balls which on the real numbers are the bounded open intervals.

Comment: "Closed intervals can be singletons, so the topology generated by the closed intervals is the discrete topology. Not very interesting, not very useful." Yes, I should have thought about that. So what is it specifically that we cannot do with that topology that we can do we the topology generated by the set of $(a,b)$. (note, I've never formally studied topology, so I'm a beginner).

Comment: Characterize continuity in terms of the absolute value metric?

Comment: But we don't need topology if we can characterize continuity based on $\forall \epsilon_{>0}\exists N:n>N\to |x_n-x|<\epsilon$, do we? Are you referring to the fact that we use "$<$" rather than "$\leq$"?

Comment: Yes. But topology generalizes that. And allows you to see which arguments depend on the metric and which depend on the topology.

Comment: Frankly, it seems that you're asking "What good is topology anyway?" and not "Why is the topology on the reals generated by the open intervals".

Comment: Maybe that's what it boiled down to. But I'm beginning to understand it, thank you!

Comment: @Programmer2134 The standard topology on reals is sort of unique. It has some very good properties and any space that has those properties has to be reals (see this: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/76134/topological-characterisation-of-the-real-line ). On the other hand reals can be equiped with infinitely many different metrics that are actually equivalent (in the sense that they generate the same topology). So it also may be easier to talk about topology instead of metrics. Especially if properties (like continuity) do not depend on a metric but the underlying topology.

Answer (score 4):

By the axioms of a topology, if we'd use the proper closed intervals to generate a topology on $\mathbb{R}$, then for any $x$, $[x-1,x]$ would be "open" in this topology and so would $[x,x+1]$ be and so $[x-1,x] \cap [x,x+1] = \{x\}$ by the finite intersection axiom. So all singleton sets would be open as well, and thus **all** subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, as $A = \bigcup_{x \in A} \{\{x\}\}$ by the union axiom. So we would get the discrete topology, which is not what our intuition of $\mathbb{R}$ is, or continuity on it etc.

So we *could* take them as a generating set, but that would not give rise to an interesting topological space.
The topology generated by the open intervals (and real analysis defined in terms of this topology) was an important example when defining a general concept of topological spaces; I'd say "open sets" are named after the open intervals (open as in not including bounding points, i.e. "open-ended") and it is pleasing that these terminologies coincide in this familiar domain.

Comment: Also $[x,x]$ is a proper closed interval...

Comment: @AsafKaragila No, I mean to see non-trivial, to avoid $[x,x]$ (which we get anyway).

Comment: I see. Okay. Yeah, that's a good point.

Answer (score 2):

Because the topology $\tau$ generated by the closed intervals is another topology, not the usual one. First of all, it contains the closed intervals, which do not belongs to the usual topology. Besides, every open interval $(a,b)$ belongs to $\tau$, since, if we take $N\in\mathbb{N} $ such that $a+\frac1N\leqslant b-\frac1N$,$$(a,b)=\bigcup_{n\geqslant N}\left[a+\frac1n,b-\frac1n\right].$$So, $\tau$ is a strictly larger set than the usual topology.

Actually, $\tau$ is just the discrete topology. This is trivial if yu include singletons in the set of closed intervals (after all, $\{a\}=[a,a]$). Even if you don't do that, you know that$$\{a\}=[a-1,a]\cap[a,a+1],$$and therefore $\{a\}\in\tau$. So, why would would bother to define $\tau$ as the topology generated by the closed intervals? It is much simpler to say that $\tau=\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question right? My question is why do we do $X$ rather than $Y$, and your answer is, "because if we'd do $X$ we wouldn't be doing $Y$". I know, by why do we want to do $Y$ in the first place?

Comment: @Programmer2134 I've added another paragraph. Does it answer your question?

Comment: Ok, the question then becomes: why don't we define the topology to be $\mathcal P(\mathbb R)$, rather than $\{(a,b)|a,b\in \mathbb R\}$? But Asaf has already addressed this now. see his answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can define any topology in terms closed sets. The reason why we usually think in terms of open sets is that local properties such as continuity is defined on an open interval.

Answer (score 1):

*Why don't we define the "standard topology" as the topology generated by all the "closed intervals"?*

Because the "standard" topology should be the topology used as a "model" for the general definition. This "model topology" is the topology of the Euclidean spaces generated by the open balls (on the line, the topology generated by the open intervals).

> The concept of topological space grew out of the study of the real line and euclidean space and the study of continuous functions on these spaces. ([Munkres](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=XjoZAQAAIAAJ&q=inauthor:%22James+R.+Munkres%22&dq=inauthor:%22James+R.+Munkres%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwje2fasiZbYAhXFkpAKHVpnBdkQ6AEIJzAA), p. 75)